Sizing problem with columnSpan and rowSpan in the GridLayout qml
In the code below, when I use columnSpan and rowSpan for sizing, the rectangle with index 3 and 8 get different sizes.
import QtQuick 2.14
import QtQuick.Window 2.14
import QtQuick.Controls 2.14
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.15


Window {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("GridLayout")

    property var layoutStructure: [
        {index: 0, columnSpan: 5, rowSpan: 2},
        {index: 1, columnSpan: 5, rowSpan: 2},
        {index: 2, columnSpan: 2, rowSpan: 1},
        {index: 3, columnSpan: 2, rowSpan: 1},
        {index: 4, columnSpan: 2, rowSpan: 1},
        {index: 5, columnSpan: 2, rowSpan: 1},
        {index: 6, columnSpan: 2, rowSpan: 1},
        {index: 7, columnSpan: 2, rowSpan: 1},
        {index: 8, columnSpan: 2, rowSpan: 1},
        {index: 9, columnSpan: 2, rowSpan: 1},
        {index: 10, columnSpan: 2, rowSpan: 1},
        {index: 11, columnSpan: 2, rowSpan: 1}
    ]

    GridLayout
    {
        anchors.fill: parent
        rows: 4
        columns: 10
        columnSpacing: 0
        rowSpacing: 0

        Repeater
        {
            model: layoutStructure

            Rectangle
            {
                Layout.rowSpan: modelData.rowSpan
                Layout.columnSpan: modelData.columnSpan
                Layout.preferredHeight: modelData.rowSpan
                Layout.preferredWidth: modelData.columnSpan
                Layout.fillHeight: true
                Layout.fillWidth: true
                color: "red"
                border.width: 1

                Label
                {
                    text: index
                    anchors.centerIn: parent
                }
            }
        }
    }
}


While the rectangle with index 0 and 1 must be the same size, also the squares with index 2 to 11, but as you can see in the picture, their size is not the same.

I think this is a bug and to solve it, rowSpan and columnSpan should not be 0. When I give GridLayout rowSpan and columnSpan other than 0, the sizes are correct

You mean column spacing? Also, setting it to -1 will fix it. And yes, it looks like a bug.

A workaround, you can place an "invisible" row where columnSpan === 1:
     property var layoutStructure: [
        {c:0, r: 0, columnSpan: 5, rowSpan: 2},
        {c:5, r: 0, columnSpan: 5, rowSpan: 2},
        {c:0, r: 2, columnSpan: 2, rowSpan: 1},
        {c:2, r: 2, columnSpan: 2, rowSpan: 1},
        {c:4, r: 2, columnSpan: 2, rowSpan: 1},
        {c:6, r: 2, columnSpan: 2, rowSpan: 1},
        {c:8, r: 2, columnSpan: 2, rowSpan: 1},
        {c:0, r: 3, columnSpan: 2, rowSpan: 1},
        {c:2, r: 3, columnSpan: 2, rowSpan: 1},
        {c:4, r: 3, columnSpan: 2, rowSpan: 1},
        {c:6, r: 3, columnSpan: 2, rowSpan: 1},
        {c:8, r: 3, columnSpan: 2, rowSpan: 1},

        {c:0, r: 4, columnSpan: 1, rowSpan: 1},
        {c:1, r: 4, columnSpan: 1, rowSpan: 1},
        {c:2, r: 4, columnSpan: 1, rowSpan: 1},
        {c:3, r: 4, columnSpan: 1, rowSpan: 1},
        {c:4, r: 4, columnSpan: 1, rowSpan: 1},
        {c:5, r: 4, columnSpan: 1, rowSpan: 1},
        {c:6, r: 4, columnSpan: 1, rowSpan: 1},
        {c:7, r: 4, columnSpan: 1, rowSpan: 1},
        {c:8, r: 4, columnSpan: 1, rowSpan: 1},
        {c:9, r: 4, columnSpan: 1, rowSpan: 1},
    ]

    GridLayout
    {
        anchors.fill: parent
        rows: 4
        columns: 10
        columnSpacing: 0
        rowSpacing: 0

        Repeater
        {
            model: layoutStructure

            Rectangle
            {
                Layout.rowSpan: modelData.rowSpan
                Layout.columnSpan: modelData.columnSpan
                Layout.preferredHeight: modelData.r < 4 ? modelData.rowSpan * 100 : 0
                Layout.preferredWidth: modelData.columnSpan * 100
                Layout.fillHeight: true
                Layout.fillWidth: true
                Layout.row: modelData.r
                Layout.column: modelData.c
                color: "red"
                border.width: 1
                border.color: "black"

                Label
                {
                    visible: modelData.r < 4
                    text: index
                    anchors.centerIn: parent
                }
            }
        }
    }

[EDIT]
Another workaround, if you know the geometry that you desire, we can place position and size your Rectangles exactly:
    Item
    {
        id: grid
        anchors.fill: parent
        property int rows: 4
        property int columns: 10
        property int rowSize: height / rows
        property int columnSize: width / columns
        Repeater
        {
            model: layoutStructure
            Rectangle
            {
                x: modelData.c * grid.columnSize
                y: modelData.r * grid.rowSize
                width: modelData.columnSpan * grid.columnSize
                height: modelData.rowSpan * grid.rowSize
                color: "red"
                border.width: 1
                border.color: "black"
                Label
                {
                    visible: modelData.r < 4
                    text: index
                    anchors.centerIn: parent
                }
            }
        }
    }

You can Try it Online!

thanks Stephen. This method works, but because I send the number and dimensions of the rectangle to the backend, this method does not work for me.
